# To Find AVG per Type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Basically trying to write a query to select the movie_cost and the average movie_cost per genre. So let's say I have 3 categories of movies, drama, action, and comedy. Each movie per genre has its own type of movie_cost. How do I get the average movie_cost per genre?

Also I need to find the percentage difference between the average movie cost and the individual movie cost. I know I have to take the movie_cost minus the average movie_cost, divided by average movie_cost multiplied by 100.

So far I have gotten this and I don't know where to go from there:

```
SELECT movie_cost, AVG(movie_cost), (COUNT(movie_cost - AVG(movie_cost))/AVG(movie_cost)*100))
FROM MOVIE
GROUP BY movie_cost;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question needs more clarification.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?  The table format would also help.

Comment: Does it make more clear now?

Comment: . . Much clearer.  Sample data and desired results usually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this using analytic functions:

```
select avg(movie_cost) over (partition by genre) as average_cost,
       movie_cost,
       100 * ((movie_cost - avg(movie_cost) over (partition by genre)) /avg(movie_cost) over (partition by genre)) as diff
from movies m;
```

Comment: Percent difference is reversed. as in the positives are negatives and the negatives are positives. Also what does the 1 - do? and what does over (partition by) operation do?